# why using negative int for mod operation in toString method of Integer class in java src

Tags: java, tostring, modulo

when I read the source code of java version 1.7.0_09, I found that the realization of toString method of Integer class uses negative int to calculate the mod operation, is there any sense to that? code is as follows:

```
public static String toString(int i, int radix) {

    if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX)
        radix = 10;

    /* Use the faster version */
    if (radix == 10) {
        return toString(i);
    }

    char buf[] = new char[33];
    boolean negative = (i < 0);
    int charPos = 32;

    if (!negative) {     
        i = -i;                //***** change i to negative
    }

    while (i <= -radix) {
        buf[charPos--] = digits[-(i % radix)];   //***** change back to positive after 
                                                 //***** mod operation
        i = i / radix;
    }
    buf[charPos] = digits[-i];

    if (negative) {
        buf[--charPos] = '-';
    }

    return new String(buf, charPos, (33 - charPos));
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the algorithm, you need a stream of small (`< radix`) nonnegative integers that will fill the character buffer with digits from right to left. The standard, primary-school way to make this work is to put a sign at the beginning of the number, and then print the absolute value of the number.

But imagine if the rule were that `i` is always positive in that loop:

```
if (negative) {
    i = -i; // change i to positive
}
```

If `i` happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, then `-i` also happens to be `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) integer variables can store [exactly one more negative integer than they can store positive integers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). However, if the invariant is instead that `i` is always the *negative* absolute value, it will always fit in an `int`.

Why not just use `Math.abs()` or an `if` block? Naturally, integers are converted to strings very frequently in many computer programs, so it is useful to keep `toString` as fast as possible. The trouble is, both `Math.abs()` and `if` statements will likely be compiled to use branch instructions when compiled to machine code. [Branches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline#Branches) tend to interfere with [instruction pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline); therefore, when paying attention to performance you might choose to remove `if` statements from loops when possible.

NOTE: This kind of optimization is rarely a good idea! The performance gain is miniscule unless your code is called very very frequently (like this code) or you are building a library with lots of users and few readers/modifiers (like this code), and it makes code harder to read, understand, and change. By making this optimization, the Java engineers might speed up your code very slightly--but if you put techniques like this in code you write, your coworker/grader may not be inclined to ask Stack Overflow why your code is so hard to understand. :)

**TL;DR:** Just an educated guess, but this is a combination of two's complement math and code optimization.